# Outlook connection status check with C# VSTO using timer

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, exchange-server

I'am coding a program which should be check connection status of outlook and if not connected to server than popup a form object that write exchangeconnectionstatus value in middle.

So, for this i wrote these

```
private bool error;
Form1 form1 = new Form1();

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
  error = true;
  this.Application.Startup += Application_Startup;
}

private void Application_Startup()
{
  System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer( _ => showForm(), null, 10000, 30000);    
}

private void showForm()
{
  if (Application.Session.ExchangeConnectionMode != Outlook.OlExchangeConnectionMode.olCachedConnectedFull && error)
  {
    error = false;
    form1.setlabel(Application.Session.ExchangeConnectionMode.ToString());
    form1.Show();
  }
}
```

if i call showForm in application_startup event it works fine.
but if i call showForm in timer which trigger every 30000 miliseconds, Form object showed but freeze.

this is photo of
[worked form object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jo0d6.png)
and this is [freezed form object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS2II.png)

thats it, hope i asked question to you well.
I would be grateful anyone know this "timer event freeze" thing or can show another way for checking connection status of outlook with VSTO or addin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this situation:

Just call ShowDialog(); instead of Show();

:D

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the Timer object from the Forms namespace, not from the Threading namespace - it uses Windows messages and fires on the main thread.